# Is volatile fine with this kind of usage?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, volatile

Say I check for a variable in a loop like this.

```
while( var )
  ;
```

Here, **var** must be declared `volatile` if the program is multithreaded and **var** is accessed by multiple threads. That is a known fact. But, lets say, we have something like this.

```
while( var + 1 )
  ;
```

Will this still work with `volatile`? I mean is it possible that the compiler cache the value of **(var + 1)**? In other words, I'm asking if we need to code this like following, with **temp** being a also a `volatile` variable, to be sure no caching is done by the compiler.

```
while( temp )
  temp = var + 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Might I add that checking a var like this using `volatile` as your thread guard is not at all sufficient to prevent various and assorted race conditions from occurring.  If you are in a threaded environment, use proper locks, atomics, and/or mutex structures to grab and manipulate your vars.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same thing from the compiler's point of view. A `volatile` variable must always be re-read from memory when it's accessed. Evaluating `var` or `var + 1` both involve accessing `var`, and thus both must involve reading it back. There's no difference.